# Keep adding joptionpane input to console

Tags: java

You all have been so much help the past few months!

I have a quick question regarding JOptionPane and writing to the console. Is there a way to run a program and each time it runs, it adds to the console window? As it sits, my code will delete anything in the console window and put in new information as I write it.

My code is as follows:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Contacts {

private static java.lang.String String;

public static <NO_OPTION> void main(String[] args) {
    // contact name
    String name;
    // contact number
    String number;

    {

        String = JOptionPane
                .showInputDialog("What is the Contact's Full Name?");
        name = String;

        String = JOptionPane
                .showInputDialog("What is the Contact's Phone Number?");
        number = String;

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Contact Added!");

        System.out.append("Contact List");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        System.out.append(name + "   " + "   " + number);

    }
}
 }
```

Comment: why you are using String as a variable in your code? String is a datatype it cannot be a variable.

Comment: Good question, sir. I'm new to writing code. What do you recommend I use instead of string?

Comment: Your question not so clear. Do you want some input from JOptionpane and finally show some output in console window?

Comment: Yes sir. I would like it to add it in the console window and not clear when I run the program again.

Comment: Hope that makes sense :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help you

> If you want to save data you must use database. Or if you want to save data as long as the program alive, you can use `ArrayList`.

***Edited:***

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

class Contacts {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name;
        // contact number
        String number;

        ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> numberList = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (true) {
            name = JOptionPane
                    .showInputDialog("What is the Contact's Full Name? Press cancle to exit");

            if (name == null) {// terminate loop if name is not provided
                break;
            }
            number = JOptionPane
                    .showInputDialog("What is the Contact's Phone Number? Press cancle to exit");

            if (number == null) {// terminate loop if number is not provided
                break;
            }

            nameList.add(name);
            numberList.add(number);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Contact Added!");

            System.out.print("\nContact List");
            System.out.println();
            for (int i = 0; i < nameList.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println("--------------------------------");
                System.out.println(nameList.get(i) + "   " + "   "
                        + numberList.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at it, unfortunately, that didn't help. The program terminated after running, which then make the console go blank. I want to keep every entry in the console after the program launches every time.

Comment: If want to save your old data you must use database. Then you will get your data back whenever you run your program.

Comment: That is EXACTLY was I was looking for. I can now use this to build other things :)